# Back handspring: Hands Starting position

Tags: gymnastics

What is the proper back handspring starting position? I see two schools of thought, one with hands vertical straight up into a swing, the other is hands starting horizontal . See pictures below.

In Women's Gymnastics:
(a) Which way do judges look for and award more points?
(b) Which way do majority of the female gymnasts use?
(c) Also, is it different for Men's gymnastics by any chance (same two questions above), for judging and majority use among men athletes?

Reason it came up: My two coaches at gymnastics class were teaching different styles.

[image]

[image]